# unable to insert data in table using camel sql & sqlite Error

Tags: sqlite, apache-camel, jbossfuse, camel-sql

I am using Jboss Fuse with blueprint as DSL. I wrote a simple camel route using sql component which inserts data in SQlite.

```
   <route id="testDBRoute">
        <from uri="timer://foo?fixedRate=true&amp;period=10000"/>
        <log message="calling DB"/>
        <to uri="sql:insert into TestTable (ID, FName, LName) values (1, 'Beena', 'Singh')"/>
   </route>
```

But I got below exception in logs:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [null]; error code [1]; [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: TestTable); nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (no such table: TestTable)
```

I ran the same query in sqlite DB and the record is inserted. But the exception says it can't find either the db or the table. I have installed camel-sql and camel-spring as a feature. But I am clueless as to why its not able to connect to Sqllite DB.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you configured datasource?

Comment: Yes, like this.  <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" id="dataSourceVS">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="$[db.driver]"/>
        <property name="url" value="$[db.url]"/>
        <property name="username" value=""/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>
    <!-- configure the Camel SQL component to use the JDBC data source -->
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.sql.SqlComponent" id="sql">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceVS"/>
    </bean>

Comment: is database name mentioned in $[db.url] ?

Comment: Please note that when the file does not exist, SQLite creates a new DB. What is the actual file name?

Comment: It is something to do with your datasource configuration. Make sure the data source and sql component are getting the correct values.

Comment: Yes, The issue is with locating the database file.Its resolved now. Thanks for pointing me in the right

Comment: Can you post your solution as an answer so we can get this SO marked as answered

Comment: <cm:property name="db.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlitestudio-3.1.1/SQLiteStudio/SGMExport.db"/> instead of <cm:property name="db.url" value="jdbc:sqlite:C:/sqlitestudio-3.1.1/SQLiteStudio/SGMExport"/> did the trick. Thanks